# How can I configure Jacoco plugin in sonarqube server

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco-plugin

I have a project where I my sonarqube is in a remote server and the server has connection to SVN repository.

Now I wish to add a jacoco plugin to sonar qube which will checkout the project from SVN, build it and generate code coverage report and display it in my sonar report.
can anyone suggest what should I do for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are missing an important step. SonarQube Server will only display your report and your data, and tell you if you passed the quality gate or not and it will show you your issues. But it will not do the analyzing part.

For that you need to use a SonarQube Scanner. There are multiple scanners available as you can see [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/). Those scanners can be executed locally, or ideally will be integrated in your Continous Integration pipeline, via Jenkins, Bamboo, TeamCity, etc. This Scanner will analyze your project based on the plugins/sensors on your Sonarqube server.

This scanner has to be configured to point to your server via `sonar.host.url` property, and ideally you will have some login setup. More details regarding that can be found in the [SonarQube Documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/overview/), which i highly suggest to read.